# External CSS Not Functioning in Webhost Provider

Tags: external, web-hosting

I create a HTML file, and a CSS file to be externally referenced, both in NetBeans IDE ver 8.0.2 on a Mac Machine.

While it works as coded in the desktop, on uploading it both to the public_html folder of my hosting provider, the styles are getting applied only partially.

For example, the inner container named 'logo1' isn't getting right aligned.

**PS:** **I know that the piece of code I've pasted below will cause the text within the inner container to spill over. Please let that not be any distraction.**

My HTML Code is listed below:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- Home Page for Project 01 -->
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title> Project 01 - Key to your Technological Superiority </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="commonstyles.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="logo1">
            <!-- &#0169 is the code for the Copyright symbol -->
                <h1> Project 01 <sup>&#0169</sup></h1>    
            </div>
            <div class="footer1">
                <b> BIGGER BRIGHTER BETTER</b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My CSS Code is listed below:

```css
div.container1 {
    position:relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
    border: none;
}

div.logo1 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: rgba(57,29,75,1.0);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;                  
}

div.footer1 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 150px;
    font: Times New Roman;
    font-variant: all-small-caps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the CSS file loading correctly, i.e. have you check the path? In this fiddle, the code seems to work.

```
div.logo1 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: rgba(57,29,75,1.0);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;                  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1eyqtm18/

Comment: Well that's the most perplexing part. It works everywhere except when loaded into my file manager. In my desktop, the HTML & the CSS files are both in the same folder. So far so good. However, on uploading both of them to the **SAME** folder into the file manager in my hosting provider, weird things are happening. e.g. The verbiage "Project 01" is getting a bgcolor as mentioned in the snippet, but is not getting right justified. Kinda fed up with this over the past 2-3 days.